# Is there any way that "What" can fit in an adverbial clause?

Tags: adverbs

I think the title says everything; is there any sentence where "**What**" can fit in an **adverbial clause?**

Comment: In 'He took what I wanted', the what-clause is a noun / free relative clause, serving as the object of 'what' rather than modifying the verb _take_. See [Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/what-Clause.htm).

Comment: I'm thinking **only what** they want me to think.

Comment: @RichF Again, not an adverbial clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, it isn't modifying the verb **take**, but doesn't seem to be an adverbial clause, seems to be a noun clause, object of the verb take.

What I wanted is a skate
He took what I wanted - What I wanted - Skate.

RichF - I think that's a **noun clause**.

Comment: I'm thinking [only] what they want me to think. / I'm thinking dark thoughts. DO following the verb; noun clause / noun phrase. //// I'm thinking how they want me to think. / I'm thinking unwisely. Adverbial following the verb (adverbial clause of manner / adverb).

Comment: Only "Whatever", not "What", could introduce an adverbial clause (of concession), as in: Whatever you think, I just don't care.

Comment: As asked, this is too broad. The answer is clearly _yes_, but that’s just because you can fit more or less any word into any kind of clause.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your specific question, which does not ask whether "what" can introduce but "fit" in an adverbial clause, the answer is yes: we have the adverbial clause of concession "Come **what** may" (meaning: **No matter what** comes). In this structure, introduced by the subjunctive "come", "what" introduces a free relative but its presence is essential to express the adverbial meaning of concession.

Comment: But it's not an adverbial clause, it is a noun clause.

Comment: @Haseo It is an adverbial clause. A complete sentence could be: "Come what may, I'll stand by you" (Meaning: No matter what comes, I'll stand by you." See this for example: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=yJLdCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=%22come+what+may%22+%22adverbial+clauses+of+concession%22&source=bl&ots=obC8BZHyMD&sig=7tdgkUkprExg8L4WcONI5t4GE10&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM6rvShZvSAhUGg5AKHaYFD9sQ6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=%22come%20what%20may%22%20%22adverbial%20clauses%20of%20concession%22&f=false

Comment: And here  Quirk mentions "Come what may" as an adverbial clause: Or here: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=hgj6xZraMh4C&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=%22come+what+may%22+quirk&source=bl&ots=_H0iAakFB-&sig=y0J2JYGjNpHLZdPrkl6GR7rem5E&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixidrBhpvSAhXpB5oKHXtnAAQQ6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=%22come%20what%20may%22%20quirk&f=false

Comment: The idiomatic "Come what may" is indeed an adjunct with a fused relative as subject of "come": "whatever happens". But it is a noun phrase, not a clause.

Comment: @BillJ Why do you say it's a noun phrase? Inverted as it is, the structure does contain a verb, and is described everywhere as a clause.

Comment: @Gustavson Sorry for the delay. The subject of "come" is omitted but understood as "whatever" ("Come whatever may"). The subject and verb are inverted; the basic order would be "Whatever may come". "Whatever" is a fused relative word meaning roughly "anything which", so we understand "Anything which may come", which is a noun phrase headed by the pronoun "anything". Does that help?

Comment: @BillJ Thank you. I agree that "whatever" is the understood subject of "come" and that "anything which may happen" is a noun phrase. However, "whatever may come" (the underlying version in normal word order of "come what may") is an adverbial clause, just like "whatever happens," or "whatever you do," in sentences where they mean concession, as in "Whatever happens, everything will be all right." These clauses can be nominal only if they have a nominal function, as in: "I'll accept whaver you do (= anything you do)," where the clause in question is the direct object.

Comment: @Gustavson No, because the head of "Come what may" is the noun (or pronoun) "what", not the verb "come". Clauses always have a verb as head - NPs have nouns as head. The NP does, however, function as an adjunct, or more precisely a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: @Gustavo Also, in "I'll accept whatever you do", the element "whatever you do" is a noun phrase, not a clause. The construction is called a "fused relative" where the antecedent and the relative word are "fused" into the single word "whatever". So the noun (pronoun) "whatever" is head of the noun phrase.

Comment: @BillJ How can you tell that in “whatever happens” it is the subject and not the verb that is the head?